# Split a list with a adjustable ratio

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

so i am trying to create a function that split a list with values with an adjustable ratio.

To just split the list in half i have this function:

```
def list_splitter(list_to_split):  

    half = len(list_to_split) // 2
    return list_to_split[:half], list_to_split[half:]
```

Where list_to_split has 1000 objects. But i want to do something like this:

```
def list_splitter(list_to_split, ratio):

    part1 = len(list_to_split) * ratio
    part2 = 1 - ratio 
    return list_to_split[:part1], list_to_split[part2:]
```

So for example i want to be able to set ratio = 0.75, so that 0.75% (750 objects) is added in the first part, and 250 in the other part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, something like this should do it:

```
def list_splitter(list_to_split, ratio):
    elements = len(list_to_split)
    middle = int(elements * ratio)
    return [list_to_split[:middle], list_to_split[middle:]]
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can do like this:
>   If your ratio will change every time, then:

```
def list_splitter(list_to_split, ratio):
    first_half = int(len(list_to_split) * ratio)
    return list_to_split[:first_half], list_to_split[first_half:]
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner using numpy

```py
    import numpy as np 

    l = np.random.rand(1000)
    ratio = 0.75

    y = np.split(l, [round(len(l) * ratio)])

    print(len(y[0]), len(y[1]))
```

Output:

```bash
750 250
```

Comment: This solution actually splits the array into 3 subarrays, with the last subarray being empty. Leaving out the `len(l)` in the `np.split` call results in 2 subarrays as OP intended.

Comment: Yup, thanks for pointing this out @wlo. Updated answer based on this!